# Wordpress horizontal fields in gravity forms

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Default wordpress gravity form have vertical field like below image

[image]

Now how to make field **Middle Name** and **Surname** on the same row (example : **Surname** on the left of **Middle Name**). Another field **Give Name**  and **Email Address** still vertical ( **Give Name** above **Middle Name**, **Email Address** bellow **Middle Name**

I have try CSS but still not success

Comment: Can you show us the live site link?

Comment: i have read an article about this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/put-form-elements-on-one-horizontal-row/

Comment: Then did this article solved your problem?

Comment: i have try with css and jquery, it ok now

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found solution in here [Wordpress document](https://docs.gravityforms.com/css-ready-classes/)

just add some css class : gf_left_half, gf_right_half

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like contact form 7 plugin etc to do so!!

Here is the link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/